# Channel time out error when trying to use wcf service in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net-2.0

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9970702. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the wcf service call the close() method, after the service invocation.